# Can a Parameter in a stored procedure handle a set of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Like the title says, for example,

```
   SELECT Product_ID, Price FROM Products WHERE price > 100
```

I need to pass all the records of **"Product_ID"** to a stored procedure...

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use comma separated string.

Comment: U can use Table Valued Type

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont get what you mean... That select statement sample is inside a stored procedure and I need to call another stored procedure after getting all the product_ids... NOTE: The question above is JUST an example. Not the real problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use comma separated string / XML data type and pass to store procedure

```
Create table Product (ProductID int,ProductName varchar(100))
Insert into Product(ProductID,ProductName)
Values(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C')
```

Get list of ProductID

```
declare @productid varchar(50)
select @productid=case when ISNULL(@productid,'')='' then convert(varchar(5),ProductID) 
else @productid+','+convert(varchar(5),ProductID) end
from dbo.Product;
```

Then pass @productid to your store procedure. After that, you can parse the string and insert values into temp/variable table for processing. In the case, you want to pass more information (ProductName, Price,...), you can use XML data type.

If your SQL Server is 2008 or higher version, you can use table-value parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx

Thanks,

Comment: Used table-value parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

SELECT group_concat(CONVERT(Product_ID, CHAR(8))) FROM Products WHERE price > 100